# .htaccess throwing Internal Server Error on Linux Environment

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Years ago, something around the boom of *friendly-urls*, guided by a Firefox extension which I think was from Yahoo! Developers, offering some optimization tips after analyzing the page, giving it a grade score (sorry, I don't remember the name) I've built this **.htaccess** file:

```
# Far-away Cache Expiration
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2050 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

# Output Compression

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|html|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    # Don't compress images or already compressed files
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:avi|mov|mp3|mp4|rm|flv|swf|mp?g)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>

# Headers Fix

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

# ETag, whatever is that

Header unset ETag

FileETag None

# Rewrite Rules

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php [L]
```

Since then I've been using it in every PHP project and I've been scoring a Grade A all the time. But I used to develop always in a Windows environment.

Yesterday, for the first time, I managed to install Linux Mint and setup a development environment in a Virtual Machine.

Despite all the problems a newcomer faces in a different OS, when I tested one of the projects which was working fine in Windows, I received an Internal Server Error.

And, you may think this is ridiculous, but I never learned how to dig information from Apache's logs so I can't solve this issue by myself.

One thing I know is that if I remove everything above the `RewriteEngine On` line, Apache raises no error and the whole application works fine.

What could it be and, most important, why is this happening?

As requested in comments, the output of **apachectl -l**:

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  mod_watchdog.c
  http_core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_unixd.c
```

And the output of **apachectl -M**:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

Comment: Are there same versions of Apache running on both machines?

Comment: Take a look in /var/log/apache2/error.log, e.g. tail /var/log/apache2/error.log and post the output here, then we might be able to help.

Comment: Also check against compiled and loaded modules (`-l` and `-M` respectively for `apachectl`) whether all the modules you're using are present.

Comment: hjpotter92: I'm not sure if they're EXACTLY the same version. I mean, in Windows I usually install the latest VC9 fro ApacheLounge (2.x.x). When I installed in this Linux environment, I used only **apache2** as argument for *apt-get*. @CodeGruzzler: Now I could read it and it was complaining about the a mismatched or mispelled **Header** command. I commented all the 3 occurrences and it worked.

Comment: Every 500 error get logged in Apache's error.log. Check what it says about it.

Comment: Its says what I said they was saying (o.O): Mismatched or mispelled **Header** command. u.u'